# Cannot call attribute from file despite calling it in cmd prompt

Tags: python, python-chess

Working with this package - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-chess

In cmd I can do the following

```
>import chess
>b = chess.Board()
>print (b)

r n b q k b n r
p p p p p p p p
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
```

I then created a file called a.py, and it had these 3 lines:

```
import chess

b = chess.Board()
```

and I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "a.py", line 3, in 
>       board = chess.Board() AttributeError: module 'chess' has no attribute 'Board'

This came out of nowhere (yesterday, never had this issue) and is now an issue on both machines I tried with clean installs of python 3.5. HOW DO I FIX THIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have another file in the same directory as `a.py` with the name `chess.py`?

You can check the attributes of the `chess` module with

```
print(dir(chess))
```

Or maybe you are running different python vesions?

```
pip show python-chess
pip3 show python-chess
```

Comment: YOU GOT IT - had something called chess.py

Comment: You are welcome ;) I had this issue a couple of times, too.